# GXT Field Validation -- How can I disable the TextField validation icon?

Tags: validation, gwt, gxt

I have a Validator attached to a field. When validation fails, I want the red line to appear in the field, but I do not want the red icon to appear to the right of the field. How can I accomplish this? I don't see this functionality in the documentation. Thanks!

I also posted this on Sencha's forums but they are very slow: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?175577-How-can-I-disable-the-TextField-validation-icon&p=718440#post718440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from the Sencha forums.

> Check out Field.setMessageTarget(String) - you'll want to pass in
>   "tooltip" (or, to just not draw that icon, anything but "side"). With
>   that set, it shouldn't even attempt to draw the icon.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?175577-How-can-I-disable-the-TextField-validation-icon&p=718440

Answer (score 0):

What about converting the field in a DOM element, then navigate till the Red icon and apply a style to disable it?

Something like:

```
 ((El)passwordField.getElement().getParentElement().getChildNodes().getItem(2)).setStyleAttribute("display", "none");
```

Comment: @everyone looking for help, just look down to the other answers. dont do this

Answer (score 0):

You could have a CSS style like this :

```
.x-form-element img {
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
.x-form-item img {
  display: none;
}
```

All the images in a form element won't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

`dateField.forceInvalid("error message which u want to pass")`,.it will automaticaly show an exclamation mark on the right side of the date field